# Palavra para frases que lemos em memes da Internet

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, adjetivos, substantivos

Como devo chamar aquelas frases que muitas vezes leio, nalgumas partilhas de ‘amigos’ do facebook, em memes, como na imagem abaixo: «Na dúvida entre o certo e o errado, escolha o que lhe faz feliz». Claramente esta frase não tem grande sentido, e portanto não é boa ideia segui-la.

[image]

Comment: Em Inglês chamam'se 'captions', de maneira que suponho que seja 'legenda'.

Comment: Podes incluir um link a um exemplo ou, melhor ainda, uma imagem dessa coisa na própria pergunta? (E *meme* não leva acento.)

Comment: @Jacinto obrigado pela correcção. já editei a questão ;)

Comment: Eu chamo de "filosofia barata".  Mas isso é uma opinião pessoal.

Comment: Isso parece frase de para-choque de caminhão kkk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tal como referiu someonewithpc em inglês as frases que acompanham estas imagens ou *memes* são geralmente denominadas de *caption* que pode ser traduzida como legenda, etiqueta, título ou subtítulo.

De uma forma mais geral, eu chamá-los-ia de 'Provérbios' ou 'Dizeres Populares', 'Máximas', "Frases Feitas" ou até 'Inspirações' ou 'Frases Inspiradoras'.

Se se refere a qualidade ou veracidade do conteúdo, que muitas vezes é fraca ou deixa um pouco a desejar, podem se referir como 'filosofia barata' como diz o Centaurus, ou 'filosofia de algibeira'.

Comment: acho que gosto mais de 'frases inspiradora' ainda que seja uma tentativa falhada a frase em questão... =D

Comment: Uma frase "inspiradora" que não deu certo seria... uma "frase desesperadora"?

Comment: ...ou uma frase "expiradora"?

Comment: Poderia ser "frases de efeito", também.